# Laravel 5: insert row with possibility of duplication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How to insert row with possibility of duplication in unique column and return if item inserted or not?

tried:

`$id = DB::insert("INSERT IGNORE INTO question (id,text) values (10,'test')");`

but `$id` always return with value = `1`

tried also:

`$id = DB::table('question')->insertGetId(['id' => 10, 'text' => 'test'])->ignore();`

but `ignore()` has no effect!

Comment: Your code represents not the way Laravels `insert` function was built for. Please try it like in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts) and report us.

Comment: both ways described above, supported by Laravel 5

Comment: i am little confused with what you want to do. do you want to insert a row if it doesn't exist and return if it already exists?

Comment: I want to insert a row, and notify me if it inserted or not (cause of duplication)

Comment: have you looked into firstOrCreate / firstOrNew methods outlined on this page. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    DB::table('arv_groups')->insert([
        'grouphash' => $grouphash,
        'id_photo' => $id
    ]);
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    // I DON'T CARE IT'S DUPLICATE !!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
}
```